# how to apply user defined properties value to @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, properties, request-mapping

I have several `@RequestMapping` which value will subject to change from "/XXX" to "/V100" on someday. So I need to define it in properties. I've googled and there's way using application.properties but I have to keep "/XXX" value in a user defined properties like a "local.properties". Is it possible to define `@RequestMapping` value on a user defined properties?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/XXX")
public class MyController {
...
}
```

** **UPDATE** : tried several hours and get it to work.

my.properties

```
api.version=V100
```

mvc-context.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true" location="/WEB-INF/config/property/my.properties"/>
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping("/${api.version}")
```

tomcat log

```
localhost-startStop-1> [2016-04-28 15:01:35.410] [INFO] [RequestMappingHandlerMapping] [534] Mapped "{[/V100/detail],methods=[GET]}"...
```

Comment: `@RequestMapping("/XXX")` is equivalent to `@RequestMapping(value = "/XXX")` and _value_ must be assigned a constant expression, so I don't think what you seek is possible.

Comment: @MarcTarin Isn't it possible? Writing the value in the application.properties file and use `@RequestMapping("#{id.of.the.prop}")` will work. I'm looking for a way to write a value to user defined properties...

Comment: problem solved. see UPDATE section...

Comment: my bad, I actually learned something thanks to you.

Comment: With Spring Boot there is also a [command line option](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) to add extra property files.

Comment: @MarcTarin Yes, spring boot is good choice but our project not using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the xml solution provided by @JustinB, here is an annotation-only solution (tested with Spring Boot):

```
@Controller
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/user.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@RequestMapping("/${api.version:}")
public class MyController {

...

}
```

The value of `api.version` is read from If *src/main/resources/user.properties* if it exists. If the file is missing or `api.version` is not set, it will default to an empty string.

Beware, if `api.version` is also defined in *application.properties* it will take precedence whether or not *user.properties* exists and `api.version` is set in it.

More examples of @PropertySource are provided [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/).

Comment: Much simpler version!