# How to assign annotation value from application.properties in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an entity/model with discriminator formula and now I'm assigning a discriminator formula like the following sample,

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorFormula("type")
class Student {
    // code
}
```

In the same case, how can I assign discriminator value from `application.properties` in Spring Boot?

Comment: look into `@Value` annotation

Comment: @DiscriminatorFormula(@Value = "${type}") is this  way correct? @pandaadb

Comment: I think `@Value` annotation is disallowed for this location.

Comment: You cannot... Annotation values need to be static.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank for the answer.

Comment: Did you try @DiscriminatorFormula("${your.app.discriminator-formula}") where your.app.discriminator-formula is a property in application.properties?

Comment: @jeeva check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36915835/5873923) I gave to a similar question. I haven't tested your case, but luckily it will work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The expression in the class level annotation should be a constant, i.e., `final` and `static`. What you are trying to achieve is not possible. The best you can do is read it from a constant file rather than application.properties.

Comment: Basically, you are not correct when saying "is not possible". What @jeeva wants to achieve is possible and doable but requires customising the Hibernates Annotation Binder. It can lead to problems, it is hard to do but possible and doable.