# Is there a way to insert spring properties (key or value) exactly into annotation value[Spring]

Tags: java, spring

I want to inject spring properties into Annotation but I can't do it directly.
I have annotation :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@StepDefAnnotation
@Documented
public @interface When {
    String value();

    long timeout() default 0L;
}
```

And I want to insert it like this `@When(value="some.value.from.properties")`
or like this `@When(value=@Value("some.value.from.properties"))`

Comment: Why don't you use the `ConditionalOnProperty` from Spring? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to apply user defined properties value to @RequestMapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885641/how-to-apply-user-defined-properties-value-to-requestmapping)

Comment: Look at this, @Adriano: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350961/spring-expression-language-in-custom-annotation

Comment: @MarcTarin: ???

Comment: @Sofo Gial I want to insert property into another annotation property not on Simple java property. I think that wont be work